# JIRA REST API to get work log - "You do not have the permission to see the specified issue"

Tags: error-handling, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to get work log of a specified issue on Jira. According to this document https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e774 I'm using this format giving my issue id:

> /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/worklog

Although I have logged in Jira, I got this error:

> {"errorMessages":["You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.","Login Required"],"errors":{}}

Besides, I can see work log on Jira's interface. I don't think there is an permission constraint. Any help to solve?

Comment: For newbie developers, I use /rest/auth/1/session and send my username and password using Postman, a Chrome extension. After authentication, you will not get this error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You REST API request need to be authenticated. Please read Authentication paragraph (4th from the top): https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

The easiest way is to use /rest/auth/1/session: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e3737

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue when trying to use Cookie-Based authentication, I was following this guide from Atalassian; https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-cookie-based-authentication

The guide mentions the need for `JSESSIONID` but does not mention you'll also need to supply `studio.crowd.tokenkey`, really check what cookie elements you get back when you authenticate in case they change it again, and don't update documentation.

For my own sake I noted down all the code [here](http://blog.nick.josevski.com/2016/04/08/jira-cookie-based-auth-api-calls-in-f-with-restsharp/).