# Python request.session JIRA "You do not have the permission to see the specified issue"

Tags: python-2.7, session, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

Firstly, I am aware of the solution presented here: [JIRA REST API to get work log - "You do not have the permission to see the specified issue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434628/jira-rest-api-to-get-work-log-you-do-not-have-the-permission-to-see-the-speci) ... As well the [linked](https://blog.nick.josevski.com/2016/04/08/jira-cookie-based-auth-api-calls-in-f-with-restsharp/) blog post (*penned by* @Nick Josevski), which whilst useful, doesn't address my specifc problem, which could be something trivial...

With following **Python 2.7.3** code...

```
import requests
import getpass
import json

jira_user = raw_input("Username: ")
jira_pass = getpass.getpass()

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = jira_ca_certs # Our internal certs
auth_info = {"username": jira_user, "password":  jira_pass}
login_url = 'http://JIRA_SERVER.com/login.jsp'
session.post(login_url, data=auth_info)
```

I generate the cookies post basic authenticatation to jira (note: *I am using "http" without specifying the PORT to authenticate with the login page*).. As session automatically holds the returned cookies, I can use *session.cookies* to set the header:

```
cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'cookie': cookies}
```

Following which, I test the captured cookies with a basic get to the secure JIRA url, using **https** + **PORT**:

```
base = session.get('https://JIRA_SERVER.com:1234', headers=headers)
print 'base: ', base
```

The above, as expected, returns (*though this might not be a valid test?*) ...

```
base:  <Response [200]>
```

Now to test the code for it's *intended purpose*. I extend the url for a specific JIRA issue, using the same approach:

```
jira = session.get('https://JIRA_SERVER.com:1234/rest/api/latest/issue/KRYP-6207', headers=headers)
print 'issue: ', jira
print jira.json()
```

With JSON output, I get a response stating I *do not have the permission*:

```
issue:  <Response [401]>
{u'errorMessages': [u'You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.', u'Login Required'], u'errors': {}}
```

The cookies returned, that I use in the header, are:

```
headers:  {'cookie': 'atlassian.xsrf.token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|lout; Path=/, JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/'}
```

I don't know *why* this works for the *base* url, but not the *issue* url.. I have used *Chrome POSTMAN* to check the cookies being returned, and they are the same as those listed above i.e. atlassian.xsrf.token, and JSESSIONID.

Hoping someone here can tell me what I am doing wrong! Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are not correctly logged in? based on the requests I saw in webbrowser developer tools, I created following requests and it worked with our JIRA:

```
import requests
import getpass
import json

jira_user = raw_input("Username: ")
jira_pass = getpass.getpass()

session = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Host': 'our.jira.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://our.jira.com/login.jsp',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

data = [
  ('os_username', jira_user),
  ('os_password', jira_pass),
  ('os_destination', ''),
  ('user_role', ''),
  ('atl_token', ''),
  ('login', 'Anmelden'),
]

loginPost = session.post('https://our.jira.com/login.jsp', headers=headers, data=data)

xsrf_token = session.cookies.get_dict()['atlassian.xsrf.token']
jsessionid = session.cookies.get_dict()['JSESSIONID']



cookies = {
    'atlassian.xsrf.token': xsrf_token,
    'JSESSIONID': jsessionid,
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'our.jira.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

r = session.get('https://our.jira.com/rest/api/latest/issue/SDN-206', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print r.json()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I actually tried by using base64 for my credentials, and passing those into the POST header instead, which worked! ...So was very likely something I mistyped! .. NOTE: Not sure if were setting the cookies as an example? .. but you don't need to specify them for session as they are automatically managed e.g. I'm simply using: jira = session.get('https://my.jira.com:1234/rest/api/latest/issue/KRYP-1234')

Comment: yes i know, i just converted the curl command of the http request into python code using curl.trillworks.com
like you said I used the cookies just to display wich ones are required for my request to pass